# Removing multiple layers in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, layers, react

I have created a project where I need to add and remove multiple layers in OpenLayers. The layers are from shapefiles that are available on a node server. I loop trough a list of all the names of the files and add them one by one to the map.

```
  setShapeFile(shapefiles) {
    this.clearAllBoundriesLayers();
    this.resetShapefileColors();
    shapefiles.forEach((shapefile) => {
      let vectorSource = new VectorSource({
        format: new GeoJSON(),
        loader: (extent, resolution, projection) => {
          var url = "http://localhost:3030/api/getShapefile/" + shapefile.file;
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          let color = this.getshapefileColor();
          xhr.open("GET", url);
          var onError = function () {
            vectorSource.removeLoadedExtent(extent);
          };
          xhr.onerror = onError;
          xhr.onload = () => {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
              var features = vectorSource
                .getFormat()
                .readFeatures(xhr.responseText);
              features.forEach((feature) => {
                feature.setId(feature.get("OBJ_ID"));
                feature.setStyle(
                  new Style({
                    fill: new Fill({
                      color: color,
                    }),
                    stroke: new Stroke({
                      color: "#000000",
                      width: 0.5,
                    }),
                  })
                );
              });
              vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
            } else {
              onError();
            }
          };
          xhr.send();
        },
        strategy: bboxStrategy,
      });
      let vector = new Vector({
        //minZoom: 13,
        source: vectorSource,
      });
      vector.set("name", "plotShapefileLayer" + shapefile.type);
      this.map.addLayer(vector);
    });
    console.log("-----------------------");
    this.map.getLayers().forEach((layer) => {
      console.log(layer);
      console.log(layer.get("name"));
    });
  }
```

In the console log I do at the end all of my layers are visible with the correct names.

But when I try to remove the layers only the first layer gets removed and the other ones stay visible. The layer objects become unidentified. So I was thinking that by removing the first layer all the other ones there reference to the layer gets removed but the layer self stays on the map. I have tested if the method to remove the layers doesn't get accidentally called, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Here is the code where I remove the layers:

```
clearAllBoundriesLayers() {
    console.log("-----------------------");
    this.map.getLayers().forEach((layer) => {
      console.log(layer);
      if (layer !== undefined) {
        console.log(layer.get("name"));
        if (layer.get("name") !== undefined) {
          if (
            layer.get("name") === "plotBoundriesLayer" ||
            layer.get("name") === "plotUserBoundriesLayer" ||
            layer.get("name") === "plotUserBoundriesLayerIcons" ||
            layer.get("name").includes("plotShapefileLayer")
          ) {
            layer.getSource().clear();
            this.map.removeLayer(layer);
          }
        }
      } else {
        this.map.removeLayer(layer);
      }
    });
    if (this.select) {
      this.select.getFeatures().clear();
    }
  }
```

Comment: You are removing elements from an array while looping through the array you are changing.  You should take a copy of the array using slice before calling forEach `this.map.getLayers().getArray().slice().forEach((layer)`

Comment: @Mike Thank you very much! That was the problem. Is there any documentation on how this works?